# Matrix block Element API call on null error

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I get this JSON error when trying to output content of a matrix block called proLinks using the Element API.

> Call to a member function all() on null

The code is as follows (I've shortened it and removed the other content, this is the only one that I can't get to work):

```
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'discproj.json' => function() {
      return [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => ['section' => 'dPs'],
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

          $linkBlocks = [];
          foreach ($entry->proLinks->all() as $block) {
            switch ($block->type->handle) {
              case 'external':
              $linkBlocks[] = [
                'externalTitle' => $block->externalTitle,
                'externalLink' => $block->externalLink,
              ];
              break;
            }
          }

          return [
            'projectLinks' => $linkBlocks,
          ];
        },
      ];
    },
  ]
];
```

I've looked at the other questions about this here, and they all seem to do things a little bit different from each other. I think I have the general structure, but there is obviously something missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Not every entry uses the matrix block, the error appears when the script hits that empty/non-existing block (null) it can't go looking for something inside it. Adding a conditional around the foreach solves it.

```
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'discproj.json' => function() {
      return [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => ['section' => 'dPs'],
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

          $linkBlocks = null;
          if ($entry->proLinks) {
            foreach ($entry->proLinks->all() as $block) {
              switch ($block->type->handle) {
                case 'external':
                $linkBlocks[] = [
                  'externalTitle' => $block->externalTitle,
                  'externalLink' => $block->externalLink,
                ];
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          return [
            'projectLinks' => $linkBlocks,
          ];
        },
      ];
    },
  ]
];
```